# Select all array type along with dimension

Tags: postgresql

While using array data type in postgres, I have encountered the situation where I need to extract the dimension along with data type.

```
dellstore_clear=# \d+ sal_emp
                                              Table "public.sal_emp"
     Column     |   Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
----------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 name           | text      |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 pay_by_quarter | integer[] |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 schedule       | text[]    |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
Access method: heap

dellstore_clear=#
```

The dimension of a column can be retrieved using the following

```
dellstore_clear=# select array_ndims(pay_by_quarter) as pay_by_quarter_dim, array_ndims(schedule) as schedule_dim from sal_emp limit 1 ;
 pay_by_quarter_dim | schedule_dim
--------------------+--------------
                  1 |            2
(1 row)

dellstore_clear=#
```

I am trying to combine these two while retrieving the info from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` as follows,

```
select column_name, 
case 
    when data_type='ARRAY' then udt_name::regtype::text
    else data_type
end as column_type,
case
    when data_type='ARRAY' then array_ndims(column_name)
    else 'NA'
end as array_dimension

from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_CATALOG LIKE 'dellstore_clear' and TABLE_SCHEMA like 'public' and TABLE_NAME like 'sal_emp' order by ordinal_position;
```

But, this gives error as follows,

```
ERROR:  function array_ndims(information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist
LINE 7:     when data_type='ARRAY' then array_ndims(column_name)
                                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
dellstore_clear=#
dellstore_clear=#
```

How to pass the retrieved column name value to the subsequent functions in the same query ?

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL for that, which requires a PL/pgSQL routine or anonymous code block. Your first example passes the actual array into the function, while your second example passes a text value holding the name of the column. With dynamic SQL you can use the column name to construct a query that references it the way your first example does, then [`execute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) it.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is not required. There is no need to include `table_catalog` in the selection criteria since all rows will have the same value (the current database). Don't use `LIKE` to test for equality. While the table DDL can be inferred from the post's content, it would be better to include the actual table DDL. Also include sample data if appropriate and the expected output. It's unclear whether the desire is to display the declared dimensions or the actual dimension for each row in the data table. I've assumed the former in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following demonstrates using the system catalog `pg_attribute` to retrieve the number of array dimensions for each column:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dims_demo;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dims_demo (
  id INTEGER GENERATED always AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  a1 INTEGER[],
  a2 INTEGER[][]
);

SELECT column_name,
       CASE
         WHEN data_type = 'ARRAY' THEN udt_name::regtype::text
         ELSE data_type
       END AS column_type,
       CASE
         WHEN data_type = 'ARRAY' THEN a.attndims
       END AS array_dimension
  FROM information_schema.columns c
  JOIN pg_attribute a
    ON a.attrelid = (FORMAT($$%I.%I$$, c.table_schema, c.table_name))::regclass
       AND a.attname = c.column_name
  WHERE c.table_schema = CURRENT_SCHEMA()
    AND c.table_name = 'dims_demo'
  ORDER BY c.ordinal_position;
```

When run, the following output is produced:

| column_name | column_type | array_dimension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | integer | [null] |
| a1 | integer[] | 1 |
| a2 | integer[] | 2 |

The number of dimensions that is returned is based on the table definition. PostgreSQL does not enforce [the declared](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION) number of dimensions, so an array column can hold an arbitrary number of dimensions regardless of the column type specification.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example passes the actual `array` into the function, while your second example passes a `text` value holding the name of the column.
Another problem is with your `case` statement: the db will check the validity of that call *before* it tries to evaluate the `case`. Simpler example:

```sql
select case when false 
       then this_function_exists(but_not_with_this_type) end 
from sal_emp;
```

That function call fails even though logically, `when false` should prevent it from ever taking place.

Another issue is with the attempt use `case` to either return a result of `array_ndims()`, which is `int`, or `'NA'`, which is `text`. All options in a `case` must be of the same type, or coercible thereto, so you need to trade that `'NA'` for a `null`, or `cast(array_ndims() as text)`. The former is preferable:

```sql
case
    when data_type='ARRAY' then array_ndims(column_name)
    else null
end as array_dimension
```

---

With [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) you can use the column name to construct a query that references it the way your first example does, then `execute` it. The `case` can be evaluated *outside it* so that when it's `false`, the query won't even get to have that function call in it. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/D0Acrdba)

```
create function get_array_types_and_dims(p_schema_name text,p_table_name text)
  returns table (column_name text,
                 column_type text,
                 array_dimension int) as $f$
declare r record;
begin
  for r in select isc.column_name,isc.udt_name,isc.data_type
           from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc
           where isc.TABLE_SCHEMA like p_schema_name
           and isc.TABLE_NAME like p_table_name
           --isc.TABLE_CATALOG LIKE 'dellstore_clear'
           order by isc.ordinal_position 
  loop
  return query execute format($dyn_sql$
     select %2$L,
            case when $1='ARRAY' then $2::regtype::text
                 else $1::text
            end as column_type,
            %3$s as array_dimension
     from %1$I.%2$I
   $dyn_sql$, 
   p_schema_name,
   p_table_name,
   case when r.data_type='ARRAY' 
        then format('array_ndims(%1$I)',r.column_name)
        else 'null::int'
   end)
   using r.data_type,
         r.udt_name;
  end loop;
end $f$ language plpgsql;

select * from get_array_types_and_dims('public','sal_emp');
```

| column_name | column_type | array_dimension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sal_emp | text | *null* |
| sal_emp | integer[] | 1 |
| sal_emp | text[] | 2 |

`%1$I`, `%2$I`, `%2$L` and `%3$s` are [`format()` placeholders](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) corresponding to the parameters in the parentheses, `$1` and `$2` are placeholders for parameters passed to [`execute` in the `using` part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) after that.

`$f$` and `$dyn_sql$` are [tagged/named quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).

Comment: There is no need to use dynamic SQL. If the table is empty, then no rows are returned. If an array column is NULL, then no dimension count is returned. Multiple rows will be returned if more than one row is in the table. `LIKE` should not be used for testing equality.

Comment: The point's clear from the answer you already posted. OP and me get notified - you don't need to repeat it the question comments and again under all previous answers. Main focus here is a demonstration of how you can use an identifier found in a catalog, as an identifier referenced by your query and making a function not just conditionally called, but entirely conditionally evaluated. That's what the question actually was: *"How to pass the retrieved column name value to the subsequent functions in the same query ?"* and that's what I attempted to answer and demonstrate.

Comment: @JohnH That being said, I believe this thread is a typical [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and I appreciate you addressed the X, while I also believe the Y here is fun to explore and at times - even if it's not necessarily one of them - useful to know.